# Safari not scaling images and container properly after update

Tags: css, reactjs, web, next.js, safari

After last update of MacOS and Safari layout one of my pages collapsed.
The whole layout is based on REMs (including the sizes of the images and containers), so the size of all elements should be calculated based on the font size, which is also dynamic and depends on the screen width. Currently, when the screen width is shrinking, font size is also getting smaller, however, only the text is getting smaller, and not the whole layout. Everything works perfectly fine in e.g. Chrome, worked also in Safari until the last update.

Did any of you also had this problem? Thank you in advance for your help!

Link to the website: https://appsclinic.vercel.app/

Searched in Google for similar case, so far not found.